# Having issues in power digit sum in C++

Tags: c++

2^15 = 32768 and the sum of its digits is 3 + 2 + 7 + 6 + 8 = 26.

What is the sum of the digits of the number 2^1000?

currently I am working on power digit sum in C++. my program is working properly but it gives inappropriate output.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

long double calculate(long double n)
{
    long double i,j,temp = 0,sum = 0;
    while(n != 0)
    {
        temp = fmod(n,10);
        sum = sum + temp;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
int main()
{
    long double i,j,n = 1000,temp = 1,value = 0;
    for(i = 1;i <= n;i++)
    {
        temp = temp * 2;
    }
    cout << "Multiplication is : " << temp << endl;

    value = calculate(temp);
    cout.precision(100);
    cout << "Sum is : " << value << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting o/p like this.

```
Multiplication is : 1.07151e+301
Sum is : 1200.63580205668592182366438692042720504105091094970703125
```

it shouldn't be in points.it should print in digits.

Comment: Can you please show an example of the output you *want*?

Comment: sum should be 1366

Comment: Why not use the pow function instead of having a loop multiply by 2 each time? Also, your calculations are in double, so you are probably getting the little floating points add up.

Comment: @Eyal K. the same getting the same answer.

Comment: Why are you using `double` when you know all the outputs will be integers?

Comment: You're dealing with integers and using doubles to calculate. Try using long longs instead and see what happens

Comment: @AvantikaSaini no int type can represent 2^1000

Comment: "working properly but it gives inappropriate output". You can describe the situation in a more concise manner: "it doesn't work".

Comment: The sum of BINARY digits for 2 to power of 1000 is 1   ;)

Answer (score 5):

Representing 2^1000 in binary would take a 1000 bits. Doubles are only 64bits long (long doubles are 80 or 128 bits depending on compiler/architecture). So doubles represent 2^1000 approximately. The input to `calculate` isn't 2^1000, but rather as close an approximation to it as 80bits allow. That approximation does not contain the lowest digits that `calculate` would like to sum over.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use any primitive datatype to calculate 2^1000 and later sum of its digits, as its a big number (however, in languages like python and ruby you can do it).

For solving this problem in C/C++, you have to use array (or any other linear data structure like linked list, etc) and apply logic similar to usual pen-paper method of multiplying numbers.

First try to find a bound on number of digits in 2^1000 and then initialize an integer array of size greater than it with all zeroes. Keep the last element to be 1. Now multiply the array (thinking it as a large number such that each digit is in a different cell of the array) with 2, thousand times, taking modulo and carry overs.

Here is the code for above logic:

```
int ar[303];
int sum =0;
ar[0]=1;
for(int j=1;j<303;j++)
    ar[j]=0;
for(int i=1;i<1001;i++)
{
    ar[0]=2*ar[0];
    for(int k=1;k<303;k++)
        ar[k]=2*ar[k] + ar[k-1]/10;
    for(int j=0;j<303;j++)
        ar[j]=ar[j]%10;
}
for(int i=0;i<303;i++)
sum = sum + ar[i];
cout<<sum;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting your sum with decimal points is because you are dividing a **double** by 10. This will not result in a clean integer unless the doubles last digit before the decimal point is a zero.

example:
376 / 10 = 37.6

370 / 10 = 37

To solve this change this in your code on line 12:
n = (n-temp)/10;

This will cut the float numbers from your sum at least.

Answer (score 0):

finally i have solved my problem.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

long double calculate(string n)
{
    long double i,j,temp = 0,sum = 0;
    for (i = 0;i < n.length();i++)
    {
        if(n[i] == '.')
        {
            break;
        }
        sum = sum + (n[i] - 48);
    }
    return sum;
}
int main()
{
    long double i,j,n = 1000,temp = 1,value = 0;
    string str;
    temp = pow(2,n);
    cout << "Power is : " << temp << endl;
    str = to_string(temp);
    cout << str << endl;
    value = calculate(str);
    cout.precision(100);
    cout << "Sum is : " << value << endl;
    return 0;
}
```